# Updating htaccess to force https and remove .php causes a redirect loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

My htaccess currently removes the php file extension and trailing slashes from URLs. So that's great.

However, I've just bought an SSL certificate, and followed [these instructions](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/ssl/how-to-force-https-using-the-htaccess-file) to force any URLs to show off my newly-bought SSL certificate (the website handles personal and financial info, so it's a big selling point).

Below is my .htaccess file, with the https:// rewrite in the `# NEW CODE` block. However, when I try to load the website, I get a `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` response in Chrome.

```
RewriteEngine On

# NEW CODE
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
# END NEW CODE

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

.htaccess files are not my forté, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: And everything works fine without the NEW CODE, no redirect loops?

Comment: Is there a load balancer in front of this web server?

Comment: @DusanBajic I'm not aware of any load balancer on the server, and everything was working fine with the original (i.e., without the NEW CODE section, and the http URLs, rather than the https)

Comment: What happens if you remove NEW CODE, and try https://example.com, does ti work?

Comment: that is `https://example.com` in the comment above

Comment: So, without the http://?

Comment: I mean, try `https://example.com` to make sure https site is correctly configured

Comment: Ah ok. Yes, when I visit `https://example.com`, the certificate/padlock shows up fine

Comment: do you have access to apache .conf files?

Comment: No, I'm on shared hosting at the moment (TsoHost), and I don't have access to it

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
# NEW CODE
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
# END NEW CODE
```

to:

```
# NEW CODE
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
# END NEW CODE
```